# Sum of odd numbers using while loop in python

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and was asked to sum odd numbers from 1 to (2*n)-1 using a while loop. 
This is my attempt:

```
def sum_odd_n(n):
    while n<2*n:
        sum = 0
        if n%2==1:
            sum = sum+n
    return (sum)
```

May i know my mistake? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: When will "n<2*n" ever be false?

Comment: Also, you never change `n`, and you reset 0 every time you *would* have a new `n`.

Answer (score 3):

The condition `while n<2*n:` is always true while `n >= 0`, you'll have an infinite loop. Try the following

```
def sum_odd(n):
    value = 1
    total = 0
    while value < (2*n) - 1:
        if value % 2 == 1:
            total += value
        value += 1
    return total

>>> sum_odd(25)
576
```

For completeness the more pythonic way to handle this would be using `sum` with a generator expression

```
def sum_odd(n):
    return sum(i for i in range(1, 2*n -1) if i%2 == 1)
```

Comment: while condition must be <=, because it must be inclusive according to what the question says

Comment: Note `sum(i for i in range(1, 2*n -1) if i%2 == 1)` could be shortened to `sum(i for i in range(1, 2*n -1) if i%2)` or `sum(i for i in range(1, 2*n -1) if i&1)`

Answer (score 1):

The first hint would be to take a look at your condition in while loop:

```
while n < 2*n
```

Notice that this will always be true, because if `n>0`, then `2*n` is always greater. If you need more help, write a comment ;)

**UPDATE:** I will just tell you what is wrong so if you want to try it out first on your own, stop reading. So basically you need another variable, let's say `i` that will loop through integers. Then you can do something like this:

```
def sum_odd_n(n):
    i = n
    sum = 0
    while i < 2*n:
        if i % 2 == 1:
            sum += i
        i += 1
    print sum # for python3: print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def sum_odd_n(n):
...     return sum([2 ** i  for i in range(0,n,1) ])
... 
>>> sum_odd_n(2)
3
>>> sum_odd_n(5)
31
>>>
```

Comment: *"was asked to sum odd numbers from 1 to (2*n)-1 **using a while loop**"* this solution produces the correct behavior but doesn't satisfy the question requirements

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to point out the mistakes you have done, and try to offer corrections.

```
def sum_odd_n(n):
while n<2*n: # n will always be less than ('<') 2*n. For eg, if n=5, 5<10.
    sum = 0 # you are resetting the sum at every iteration. We need to take this outside.
    if n%2==1:
        sum = sum+n
return (sum)
```

Here's what I think should work.

```
def sum_odd_n(n):
  sum = 0  # sum is initialized here, so that it doesn't reset inside the loop
  iterator = 0
  while iterator<2*n
    if iterator%2==1:
      sum = sum+iterator # or sum += iterator
    iterator = iterator + 1 # otherwise this will be an infinite loop, as iterator will always be 0.
  return sum
```

Hope this works for you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```py
def sum_odd(n: int):
    total = 0
    for x in range(2*n):
        if x%2==1:
           total += x
    return total
```